# R Generate sequence of IP numbers

Tags: r

Starting with:

```
   OrigID  IP1              IP2
        1  111.111.111.250  111.111.112.005
```

Desired output:

```
   OrigId  IP1              IP2              IP
        1  111.111.111.250  111.111.112.005  111.111.111.250
        1  111.111.111.250  111.111.112.005  111.111.111.251
        1  111.111.111.250  111.111.112.005  111.111.111.252
        1  111.111.111.250  111.111.112.005  111.111.111.253
        1  111.111.111.250  111.111.112.005  111.111.111.254
        1  111.111.111.250  111.111.112.005  111.111.111.255
        1  111.111.111.250  111.111.112.005  111.111.112.001
        1  111.111.111.250  111.111.112.005  111.111.112.002
        1  111.111.111.250  111.111.112.005  111.111.112.003
        1  111.111.111.250  111.111.112.005  111.111.112.004
        1  111.111.111.250  111.111.112.005  111.111.112.005
```

Basically, generating the list of `IP` from `IP1` to `IP2`. It needn't be in the same data frame, but is displayed that way here, for brevity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `iptools` library can help here. For example with your input data

```
dd <- read.table(text=" OrigID  IP1              IP2
1  111.111.111.250  111.111.113.005", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

we can write a helper function

```
library(iptools)
ip_range <- function(start, end) {
  numeric_to_ip(ip_to_numeric(start):ip_to_numeric(end))
}
```

and can then use that to expand the rows, here using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)    
dd %>% rowwise() %>% do({data.frame(., IP=ip_range(.$IP1, .$IP2))})
```

to get

```
   OrigID IP1             IP2             IP             
 *  <int> <fct>           <fct>           <fct>          
 1      1 111.111.111.250 111.111.113.005 111.111.111.250
 2      1 111.111.111.250 111.111.113.005 111.111.111.251
 3      1 111.111.111.250 111.111.113.005 111.111.111.252
 4      1 111.111.111.250 111.111.113.005 111.111.111.253
 5      1 111.111.111.250 111.111.113.005 111.111.111.254
 6      1 111.111.111.250 111.111.113.005 111.111.111.255
 7      1 111.111.111.250 111.111.113.005 111.111.112.0  
 8      1 111.111.111.250 111.111.113.005 111.111.112.1  
 9      1 111.111.111.250 111.111.113.005 111.111.112.2  
10      1 111.111.111.250 111.111.113.005 111.111.112.3  
# ... with 258 more rows
```

If you really want to format with leading zeros, you can write a formatter. For example in base R

```
format_ip <- function(x) {
  sapply(lapply(lapply(strsplit(x, ".", fixed=TRUE), as.numeric), function(x) sprintf("%03d", x)), paste0, collapse=".")
}
```

or slightly more readable with purrr

```
library(purrr)
format_ip <- function(x) {
  x %>% strsplit(".", fixed=TRUE) %>% 
    map(~sprintf("%03d", as.numeric(.))) %>% 
    map_chr(paste0, collapse=".")
}
```