# How to get a list of IP addresses from an IP range using R?

Tags: r

I have log data in which one of the columns have IP ranges and the next column is corresponding ports. Eg:

```
IPRange                             Port
192.100.176.0-192.100.179.255       A, B, C
```

I need to expand the IPRange column into a list of network blocks till 3rd octet:

```
IPRange                         IP                  Port
192.100.176.0-192.100.179.255   192.100.176.0/24    A, B, C
192.100.176.0-192.100.179.255   192.100.177.0/24    A, B, C
192.100.176.0-192.100.179.255   192.100.178.0/24    A, B, C
192.100.176.0-192.100.179.255   192.100.179.0/24    A, B, C
```

How do I achieve this in R?

Comment: Your input and expected output seem to have no good relationship. It's important to give sample (or real) data and the expected output *given the sample input*. In this case, I don't know of a package that automatically handles IP addresses and the associated subnets/masks. There are command-line utilities (i.e., not R) that almost certainly can do this well, so I suggest you investigate those and R's `system` or `system2`.

Comment: MrFlick taught me yesterday about the `iptools` package ([link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iptools/iptools.pdf)).  Perhaps it offers the functionality your looking for.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992620/r-generate-sequence-of-ip-numbers) might help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just did some correction. Should make more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amit,

`iptools`  co-author, here.

You're in luck. Well, actually you made your own luck (as it were) b/c the fresh-off-the-compiler `iptools`  on GitHub (https://github.com/hrbrmstr/iptools) now has a `range_boundaries_to_cidr()` function. vis-a-vis:

```
library(iptools)

range_boundaries_to_cidr(
  ip_to_numeric("192.100.176.0"), 
  ip_to_numeric("192.100.179.255")
)
## [1] "192.100.176.0/22"
```

Note that it **requires** numeric inputs *and* that you *should not really expect only a single CIDR back* for some ranges given the way one has to back-compute the CIDRs. e.g.:

```
range_boundaries_to_cidr(
  ip_to_numeric("192.168.0.15"), 
  ip_to_numeric("192.168.5.115")
)
## [1] "192.168.0.15/32"  "192.168.0.16/28"  "192.168.0.32/27"  "192.168.0.64/26" 
## [5] "192.168.0.128/25" "192.168.1.0/24"   "192.168.2.0/23"   "192.168.4.0/24"  
## [9] "192.168.5.0/26"   "192.168.5.64/27"  "192.168.5.96/28"  "192.168.5.112/30"
```

You can validate my statement by running some ranges against online converters and also research a bit online as to "why".

Drop an issue on GH if you have problems with the new function as I'll see the ping from there way before I will here.